# JQuery UI boilerplate "Sortable" code not behaving properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I decided to test out some code for a "Sortable UI" from [Jqueryui.com](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/).
I copied the source code directly to notepad and saved it as sortable.html. 
When I open it up in Chrome/Firefox, nothing is draggable/droppable or otherwise sortable. It looks and behaves exactly like a plain HTML text list. Any ideas? Contents of file are in the code below.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <style>
      #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
      #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
      #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
      </style>
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
      });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <ul id="sortable">
      <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
    </ul>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you saved it as an html file and opened the file in the browser, the url will be something like 'file:///C:/temp.html'. The script references used in the file are in the format of '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js', meaning if your url is http then they'll use http, if it's https, they'll use https. Since your url will be 'file://...' it won't be able to load those references. So basically change those references to begin with "http:".

Comment: Replaced the references with your suggestion and it worked. THANK YOU!